# Wordpress woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

hey all in woo commerce plugin i add product that is variable product that is watch in different color that is good, but on from end when i show that product drop down of variation product is come but when i choose any attribute from it then related product not display only featured image display as i set when add product.
Any solution??

is there any setting from coding or functions.php file for displaying variation product and also add cart button not display on that product.

if you have any solution then please answer me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

On the Variations tab, if you click one of the variations you have added, it will drop down more details. Then you can click the square under SKU to add a photo.

Comment: Thank You But, I add it already and also fill all details related variation image.